# É uma redundância ter um único button no formulário e então atribuir type='submit' para ele?

Tags: html, phpstorm

No *PHPStorm* é dito em determinado *button*, através de um *tooltip*:

> Redundant default attribute value assingment

Quando se faz exatamente essa linha:

```
<button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="width-65 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-success">
    <span class="bigger-110">Cadastrar</span>
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right icon-on-right"></i>
</button>
```

Realmente é uma redundância ter um único *button* no formulário e então atribuir `type='submit'` somente para ele? Posso eliminar essa linha sem problemas?

Comment: Não gera problemas, o `click` em um `button` dentro de um formulário irá fazer um `submit`, então definir como `submit` é redundante

Answer (score 0):

Sim, o valor padrão do atributo `type` da tag `button` é o `submit` conforme referencia [oficial da W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html).

Portanto na teoria você pode omiti-lo sem problemas. Mas manter também não irá gerar problemas.